# Connect android mobile bluetooth with desktop for mouse and keyboard access

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid

How to connect a bluetooth with desktop and android phone. i able to parring and connect bluetooth but unable to connected with Mouse, keyboard & pen device type.

Below given are both mobile device. but A50 device connect using other app and i want to connect M30s as mouse, keyboard.

[image]

```
private  class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;
            try {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
             
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            try {
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) { }
                return;
            }

            mHandler.obtainMessage(SUCCESS_CONNECT, mmSocket).sendToTarget();
        }


        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
}
```

Comment: You want to use your A50 as a mouse for your PC?

Comment: no, Galaxy M30s i want to connect, A50 is just a demo like this.

Comment: I don't understand your goal. The galaxy A50 is obviously not a mouse or keyboard

Comment: both are mobile device. A50 connect 3rd party apps. M30 is i want to connect with my code.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.appground.blek like this

Comment: I have **edited once more** please look into **all links**

Comment: KDE Connect allows for remote input to a Windows or Linux device. It's open source, so its [source code](https://invent.kde.org/network/kdeconnect-android) could be looked at to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

## Hope this helps

- [App in Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.roarappstudio.btkontroller)
- [SourceCode in Github](https://github.com/raghavk92/Kontroller)

> Nothing to post here as code is in github

> Its in `kotlin` ,**convert to `java`** using *androidstudio*

> These one below are `java` but lacks/misses *readme*

- [1](https://github.com/shofman/BluetoothMouse)
- [2](https://github.com/nicholas23/MyBTTouchMouse)
- [3](https://github.com/coenvk/BluetoothPcControl)

Comment: This app not work. Continue force stop.

Comment: @mr.hir no it works well,but require android Pie and above(9+) .,check some other device,I have given another link check it

Comment: @mr.hir i have edited again&i think your device need to be rooted for some app to work,if that app stops,try another link I gave